# PHP sprintf escaping %

Tags: php, escaping, printf

I want the following output:-

> About to deduct 50% of € 27.59 from your Top-Up account.

when I do something like this:-

```
$variablesArray[0] = '€';
$variablesArray[1] = 27.59;
$stringWithVariables = 'About to deduct 50% of %s %s from your Top-Up account.';
echo vsprintf($stringWithVariables, $variablesArray);
```

But it gives me this error `vsprintf() [function.vsprintf]: Too few arguments in ...` because it considers the `%` in `50%` also for replacement. How do I escape it?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel My question is about vsprintf not printf, I am using this for the first time and could not assume the similarity between the two. However, searching `escape` or `escaping` in both `php.net/printf` and `php.net/vsprintf` both does not show the answer immediately. When I search for `%%` it shows the answer in php.net/printf but I didn't know about `%%`!!! Did you search for the answer there before downvoting?

Comment: @sandeepan: `vsprintf` belongs in the same family of functions as `printf`. The correct documentation to find the format, though, is http://www.php.net/sprintf. Both pages even point to it: "See sprintf() for a description of format." Didn't you at least click it?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel ok fine let's take php.net/sprintf, where is the answer? It is halfway down the page `With printf() and sprintf() functions, escape character is not backslash '\' but rather '%'.` What is there to downvote here? It was just not that obvious to me as it was to you. If you find a duplicate question you can better write the link. But I am sure many will find this question helpful.  But you won't accept that and you will still say something, I know.

Comment: oh I thought the second comment was by Col. Shrapnel , sorry

Comment: SO should have a flag for RTFM responses. It's almost like people troll just so they can tell people to read the docs. He needed help and asked a question and then someone answered helpfully and got points for it. The world went on and the internet was used to someone's benefit. Meanwhile I'm getting heated over a two year old argument.

Answer (score 435, accepted):

Escape it with another `%`:

```
$stringWithVariables = 'About to deduct 50%% of %s %s from your Top-Up account.';
```

Comment: sprintf("SELECT * FROM ... WHERE name LIKE '%%%s%%%s%%'", $fname, $lname);   --   Ugly but it works!

Comment: you can add that part with another "%s": sprintf('from %s you can get %s', 'something', '50%')

Comment: How do you escape it if the string is dynamic? Let's say,
`sprintf('This is %s.', the_title())`

Comment: @madastro `str_replace('%', '%%', the_title())`

Answer (score 11):

It is very easy.

Put another `%` in front of the original `%` to escape it.

For example,

```
$num=23;
printf("%%d of 23 = %d",$num);
```

Output:

```
%d of 23 = 23
```

Answer (score 8):

For add `%` in your language string, you just need to add **double percent `%%`** instead of one

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
sprintf(
    '%s (Cash Discount: %%%s, Deferred Discount: %%%s)',
    $segment->name,
    $segment->discount_cash,
    $segment->discount_deferred,
)

// Gold (Cash Discount: %25, Deferred Discount: %20)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
$variablesArray[0] = '%';
$variablesArray[1] = '€';
$variablesArray[2] = 27.59;
$stringWithVariables = 'About to deduct 50%s of %s %s from your Top-Up account.';
echo vsprintf($stringWithVariables, $variablesArray);
```

Just add your percent sign in your variables array

Comment: The question was how to sprintf escaping %.