# printf not print <img> tag when it has width and height set

Tags: php, html, image, printf

Ok, I want to print an 'img' from php to html. The php file is included inside a html div.
It works when I printf the image without the height and width attributes, but when I include them it stops working.

Following code works. No height or width.

```
$value='../images/cal.png';
printf (
    '<img src=%s >',
    $value
    );
unset($value);
```

Following code does not work. height and width included.

```
$value='../images/cal.png';
printf (
    '<img src=%s height=100% width=100%>',  
    $value
);

unset($value);
```

I'v tried quoting the width and height, but still nothing.
What am I missing?

It works with height and width when I use echo, but I am going to be making the code more complicated, so I want to do it in printf. Its been simplified for the question.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Sprintf but same answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666734/php-sprintf-escaping

Comment: You have invalid HTML there needs to be quotes around the 100% values. Do what @Amine suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because width and height doesn't like 100% ? Try with :

```
$value='../images/cal.png';
printf (
    '<img src=%s height="100" width="100">',  
    $value
);

unset($value);
```

Why are you making the code more complicated ? Is the following not working ?

```
echo '<img src="'.$value.'" width="100" height="100" />';
```